# Is there a way to fix my Minecraft SMP map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Due to the change in the world generation method, I went and found a map seed that was suitable for using [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-compatible-with-mc-beta-18/) to paste our old structures into it.  The only problem is, there is a region around spawn (which I moved a ways from the original staring position using the editor) that is completely uneditable.

- Blocks can neither be mined nor placed
- Doors don't function properly (door splits between the top half and lower half, changes randomly when interacted)
- Chests won't open.

Immediately outside that area, though, everything behaves fine.  I don't know if the behavior is limited to a particular chunk or not.  Could deleting something like session.lock work?  Maybe a file permissions issue?  Currently no one is using the server yet and have a backup of the world, so I should be able to fiddle with it with no risk.

Other info:

- Minecraft 1.0.0
- Vanilla server (no mods)

Any ideas?

Comment: @pppery Are both symptoms of the same cause? The questions are sufficiently different to warrant helpfulness for others, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of the vanilla minecraft server. Blocks within a certian radius of the player spawn are unbreakable to non op'ed players. This is so you can make a jail that somone connecting to the server will spawn in and only a op can let them out. This is to allow open servers but prevent drive by greifing.

I do not know if there is a way to turn this off. The best option is just move the spawn in MCEdit to somewhere outside of town.